# Easy method to create a list with elements based on the previous element

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to create a list length `l` with the function $f(x_n)=x_{n-1}+r$ where $r$ is a random real number between -1 and 1 and $x_0=1$. It got it working like this:

```
l = 50; a = Range[l]; a[[1]] = 0;
For[i = 2, i <= l, i++, a[[i]] = a[[i - 1]] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]];
a
```

But I have a feeling I'm doing it "wrong" and this can be heavily optimized and written shorter.

Any ideas ?

For example the fact that I use `Range` to create a list with elements that I never use seems wrong...

Comment: Take a look at `FoldList`/`Accumulate` and related functions.

Comment: One easy to follow method, `x = 0;Table[x = x + RandomReal[{-1, 1}], i]`, where `i` is the length of the list you desire.

Comment: `Prepend[ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 50], 1]`

Comment: Or even `NestList[# + RandomReal[{-1, 1}] &, 0, 20]`

Comment: To expand on Kuba's suggestion: `{0}~Join~Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, l]]`.

Comment: By the way, are you sure about formula? shouldn't it be `f[n] = f[n-1] +r`?

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if the first entry should be zero or one (the body of the question uses $x_0=1$ but in the code there is `a[[1]]=0`) and if it's `RandomReal` or `RandomInteger` the relevant function to use; here, the first entry in the list is set to *zero* (see `xo` below) and `RandomReal` is used to generate the random numbers.

```
(* init *)
With[{l = 50, xo = 0},

 (* make everything reproducible *)
 BlockRandom[

  (* localize the generation of random numbers *)
  Block[{r = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, l - 1]},

   (* perform the actual iteration *)
   FoldList[#1 + #2 &, xo, r]

   ], RandomSeeding -> 123]
 ]
```

---

**edit #1**

Let $X_l=\{x_t\}_{t=0}^{l-1}$ denote a series of $l$ numbers, namely $X_l=\{x_0,x_1,...,x_{l-1}\}$. Please note that when using zero-based indexing for a list of $l$ numbers, the indexes themselves run from $0$ to $l-1$.

Consider the following example: for $l=3$, the list of numbers is going to be $X_3=\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$.

Writing something like $x_s = x_{s-1} + c$, where $c$ is a *scalar* and $s$ is an index, running from $1$ to $l-1$, allows one to impose structure on list $X_l$.

A recursion like this, in the case of our example with $X_3$ above, would imply that, instead of $\{x_0,x_1,x_2\}$, list $X_3$ should-effectively-be transformed into $\{x_0,x_0+c,x_0+2c\}$ (example 1).

A further extension of the recursion model would allow $c$ to be dependent on the *recursion step*, $s$, too. In that case, the recursion would be written as $x_s = x_{s-1} + c_s$; in which case, the $X_3$ example should be modified to read $\{x_0,x_0+c_1,x_0+c_1+c_2\}$ (example 2).

Now, in the body of the question, function $f$, defines a recursion that is *seemingly* (that's *my* interpretation of the question in conjunction with the code provided) similar to the first example above ($x_s = x_{s-1} + c$, where $c$ a *scalar*); furthermore, it is explicitly stated in the question that $x_0=1$ (the first number in the sequence should be equal to one).

When ones inspects the code segment, however, one can't help but notice that the sequence `a=Range[l]; a[[1]]=0;` effectively imposes $x_0=0$ (the `a[[1]]=0` part), *contrary* to what was originally stated.

Additionally, calling `RandomReal` in `a[[i]] = a[[i - 1]] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}]` will produce a *new* random real number for *every* iteration step; this behavior implies that the relevant recursion model is that of example 2 (see above).
This, however, *contrasts* with what was initially adhered to (see quote "[...] $f(x_n)=x_{n-1}+r$ where r is a random real number between -1 and 1" from the question; here, $r$ is not dependent on the recursion step).

Having said that, if the relevant recursion model for the original question is the one exemplified in example 1, then a straightforward way to generate a list $X_l$ is

```
xo + Range[0, l-1] RandomReal[{-1, 1}]
```

On the other hand, if what's relevant for the question, is the recursion model of example 2, then a straightforward way to generate list $X_l$ is

```
FoldList[#1 + #2 &, xo, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, l - 1]]
```

**edit #2**

The use of `BlockRandom` is intended to assist in producing *reproducible* results.

For the function definition `f[x___] := RandomReal[]`, evaluating `f[]` two consecutive times will produce two different random numbers. 
On the contrary, evaluating `BlockRandom[f[]]` two or more consecutive times will *always* produce the *same* random number.

The same effect can be gotten with `BlockRandom[f[],RandomSeeding->123456789]` where `RandomSeeding` provides the seed for the random number generators (see the documentation for  [BlockRandom](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BlockRandom.html)).

The same effect as `BlockRandom` can be practically achieved by, using instead [`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom.html) before the evaluation of `f` in the example above (although there are caveats, please refer to the documentation).

What this means for this answer is that you can practically have a functioning solution without using `BlockRandom` if you choose to not use it.

According to the documentation, `BlockRandom` was introduced in 2007 (v.6.0) and was updated in 2017 (v.11.2)

Comment: I want $x_0$ as the element 1 of the list, but call it $x_0$ instead because it's the value where +r has been executed 0 times. It's a bit confusing, true. Should I edit my question ?

Comment: It is not moderators' job to review details of answers if they are more or less on topic. Please talk to Garo if you have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

I am understanding you want to generate a sequence of real numbers recursively (with some randomness) starting with $x_0=1$, Maybe this is a solution:

```
RandomSeed[2];
f[0] = 1;
f[n_Integer /; n > 0] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
l = 50; 
f[#] & /@ Range[0, l]

(*  
 {1, 1.44448, 0.663377, 0.604782, 0.675946, 0.842301, 0.430186,
  -0.239505, -0.0369893, 0.471446, 1.01369, 1.57084, 0.618061, 1.46357,
  2.44848, 2.1493, 1.23931, 1.24203, 1.50954, 1.79396, 1.57371,
  1.90365, 2.59141, 2.72949, 2.52592, 2.00322, 2.35025, 2.18926,
  2.36406, 1.38073, 2.26561, 2.80813, 2.10314, 3.03269, 3.83018, 
  3.4961, 2.9052, 3.58327, 3.08405, 2.56132, 2.79456, 3.55316, 3.36217, 
  3.1672, 3.19959, 2.78361, 2.48201, 1.85312, 2.05956, 1.12755, 1.67286}
 *)
```

The use of `SeedRandom`is for obtaining always the same sequence. I f you do not want this, and generate a different sequence every time, just comment or remove the line.